# Java RPN calculator NullPointerException error

Tags: java

I have the below code which I need to refactor but I cant get my head around why `top` is giving me a `NullPointerException` error. I have used Eclipse to debug but the only thing it is giving me is that `top` is `null`. I have commented out the `top = null` line under `RPN` method and still get the error.
The program starts by asking the user to enter a RPN expression or quit. I then enter 21+ as my input and get the error. I have looked up RPN calculators but this one seems very different to the ones I found online.
I am new to this and hope somebody can help me in the right direction.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class StackNode {
    public StackNode underneath;
    public double data;

    public StackNode(double data, StackNode underneath) {
        this.data = data;
        this.underneath = underneath;
    }
}

class RPN {
    private String command;
    private StackNode top;
    
    public void into(double new_data) {
        StackNode new_node = new StackNode(new_data, top);
        top = new_node;
    }

    public double outof( ) {
        top = top.underneath;
        double top_data = top.data;
        return top_data;
    }

    public RPN(String command) {
        //top = null;
        this.command = command;
    }

    public double get( ) {
        double a, b;
        int j;
        double val = outof( );
        
        for(int i = 0; i < command.length( ); i++) {
            // if it's a digit
            if(Character.isDigit(command.charAt(i))) {
                double number;
                // get a string of the number
                String temp = "";
                for(j = 0; (j < 100) && (Character.isDigit(command.charAt(i)) || (command.charAt(i) == '.')); j++, i++) {
                    temp = temp + String.valueOf(command.charAt(i));
                }
                // convert to double and add to the stack
                number = Double.parseDouble(temp);
                into(number);
            } else if(command.charAt(i) == '+') {
                b = outof( );
                a = outof( );
                into(a + b);
            } else if(command.charAt(i) == '-') {
                b = outof( );
                a = outof( );
                into(a - b);
            } else if(command.charAt(i) == '*') {
                b = outof( );
                a = outof( );
                into(a * b);
            } else if(command.charAt(i) == '/') {
                b = outof( );
                a = outof( );
                into(a / b);
            }else if(command.charAt(i) == '^') {
                b = outof( );
                a = outof( );
                into(Math.pow(a, b));
            } else if(command.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException( );
            }
        }

        if(top != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return val;
    }
    /* main method */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        while(true) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter RPN expression or \"quit\".");
            String line = in.nextLine( );
            if(line.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            } else {
                RPN calc = new RPN(line);
                System.out.printf("Answer is %f\n", calc.get( ));
            }
            in.close();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I have commented out the top = null line under RPN method and still get the error.

What you've remarked out is a line in a constructor. The `top` field has no initializer; therefore, `top` is null. That line you remarked out did nothing. Thus, yes, whether you remark it out or not, the code runs the same way.

Just walk through your code:

1. Your code runs `new RPN(line)`.
2. This constructor simply assigns the first parameter (which is the line of RPN-based commands the user entered) to the `command` field, and leaves `top` as `null` (whether you remark that line out or not), and that's that.
3. You then immediately run `get()` on this newly created object. This method immediately runs `outof()`.
4. `outof()` starts with the line `top = top.underneath`. The dot is the 'dereference' operator. `x.`, where `x` is null, is a nullpointerexception. Thus, that line always throws NPE.

It's that simple.

Suggestion: Learn to debug. Trying to stare at code to figure out how to fix it is not how actual programmers work. Debugging generally means to walk through the code and, 'in your head', figure out what should be happening / what you intended to happen. Compare this to what actually happens. If the two are not in agreement: Voila. You found a bug. Usually, armed with knowing exactly what you thought should happen and what actually happens, the mistake is then trivial to fix. Fix it, and continue the process. Keep going until 'what I designed it to do' and 'what actually happens' is the same all the way through.

To do this, you can use debuggers, which are baked into all major IDEs. Alternatively, just add a boatload of `System.out.println` so you know what your code is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using Eclipse debugging and the only thing it gives me is that top is null on line 23 where `top = top.underneath` is. What I understand from this calculator is that it takes input from user and adds it to the top of the stack, then it removes from the top to give you the answer. Last in first out kinda thing. Is there something I can change to make this work? I am trying really hard to understand why top is null, because its not supposed to be null as the input data should be there?

Comment: It's a bit much to ask 'can you completely redesign this code to make it work?' - that's more a job for fivr or whatnot. The problem is, there __is no value__ when you have an empty RPN stack, and yet as step 1 in your get(), you want the current value. Re-imagine the algorithm. You wrote it. Or if you didn't, ask the one who did, it's a bit hard for an outside party to guess at intent.

Comment: No worries, figured it out and got it working. Thanks for the answer though.